# RegEx for matching the month, day and year

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to find a regular expression to extract the month, day and year from a datetime stamp in this format:

```
01/20/2019 12:34:54
```

It should return a list:

```
['01', '20', '2019']
```

I know this can be solved using:

```
dt.split(' ')[0].split('/')
```

But, I'm trying to find a regex to do it:

```
[^\/\s]+
```

But, I need it to exclude everything after the space.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. Why not simply convert the string to a date data type (depending on your language/platform) and access the day, month and year parts from this date data type?

Comment: Are you using Python? / Note that *not practical* questions are not really welcomed here.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using python

Comment: @UweKeim That's the problem -- OP *knows* how to solve it already, but just want to "challenge" themself to solve it a different way.

Comment: And how are you using that regex to extract the list? `re.findall`?

Comment: Related (meta): [A car with square wheels - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are expecting the date month and year to be returned as a list, you can use this Python code,

```
import re

s = '01/20/2019 12:34:54'
print(re.findall(r'\d+(?=[ /])', s))
```

Prints,

```
['01', '20', '2019']
```

Otherwise, you can better write your regex as,

```
(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})
```

And get date, month and year from group1, group2 and group3

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXd9Y6/1)**

Python code in this way should be,

```
import re

s = '01/20/2019 12:34:54'
m = re.search(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', s)
if m:
 print([m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)])
```

Prints,

```
['01', '20', '2019']
```

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Towoth/1) might help you to do so.

```
([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+
```

[image]

#### Code:

```
import re

string = '01/20/2019 12:34:54'
matches = re.search(r'([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)', string)
if matches:
    print([matches.group(1), matches.group(2), matches.group(3)])
else: 
    print('Sorry! No matches! Something is not right! Call 911')
```

#### Output

```
['01', '20', '2019']
```

Comment: You should have waited to find out the language being used before posting this.

Comment: Your point being?  The OP is asking for a list of components.  A pure regex can't do that, for obvious reasons.

Comment: The regex is, the requirement isn't.

Comment: On second reading, it seems that OP wants a regex such that *all matching substrings* are like the required output.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely be taking advantage of Python's date/time API here.  Use `strptime` to parse your input datetime string to a bona fide Python datetime.  Then, just build a list, accessing the various components you need.

```
dt = "01/20/2019 12:34:54"
dto = datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

list = [dto.month, dto.day, dto.year]
print(list)

[1, 20, 2019]
```

If you really want/need to work with the original datetime string, then `split` provides an option, without even formally using a regex:

```
dt = "01/20/2019 12:34:54"
dt = dt.split()[0].split('/')
print(dt)

['01', '20', '2019']
```

Comment: From the question, it's obvious that OP isn't looking for a *practical* solution. Still may be useful for future readers.

Comment: I have given an option using the base string functions, in case the OP really wants to go in that direction.  But, using datetime is probably the best way to go here.